# How to use ffmpeg and javascript for user to add input box inside of a video

Tags: javascript, html, video, ffmpeg, drag-and-drop

I work on my website and the problem i faces is that i cant find a working way to get the chance for a user to drag an input box and set it into video specifying duration for the item.

so i have a video and a textbox and my problem is when i grag the box i want it to stck to the video and stay there.

Code is here:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bubble Factory Test Lab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\styles.css">
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="div1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" width="400px" heigh="300px">
        <source src="videos/CGI 3D Animated Short Film HD- 'The Answer' - by Xin Zhao & Florent Rubio.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <input type="text" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" placeholder="drag">
</body>

</html>
```